# Why doesn't Rtools 3.1 support C++11 on Windows

Tags: r, rcpp

The latest version of Rtools (3.1) does not appear to include a version of g++ that supports C++11.  Is there any particular reason for this?

Comment: There is some discussion of using C++11 with R (including Windows) in the R manuals: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Using-C_002b_002b11-code

Answer (score 11):

Precious volunteer time, maybe?

Rtools uses g++ 4.6.2. Which is totally fine for the *use by R* as R is a C program.

Now, many of us use C++ along with R (and judging from the `Rcpp` tag, you do too), and it does indeed pose a problem if you want to use features available only in g++ 4.7, 4.8, the AFAIK not-yet released 4.9, or an equivalent clang version --- *and* when you are in fact restricted to Windows.

On Linux or OS X, things are a little easier (though OS X had its own share of issue after the 10.9 release but it is getting better).

Someone needs to volunteer to provide a better / newer MinGW, or to pay someone to provide it.  If you look at old release announcements, the Rtools compiler is not upgraded all that often.  From what I can tell, there is only one R Core member working on this.  And while that particular R Core member is very knowledgeable about C++ and and the state of the g++ compiler on Windows, he is also predominatly a C programmer...

Comment: With mavericks binary builds for R 3.1.0, OSX is the best platform to do R and C++11. it just works.

Comment: As I said,  Linux tends to work too.  Having a choice between g++ 4.8 and current clang does not hurt either.  The question,  however,  was about Windows...

Answer (score 11):

I am going to work on this. Having a tool set on windows that allows C++11 might be what is stopping wide adoption of Rcpp11. And I'd definitely like people to start using Rcpp11. I'm buying a windows box next week for this (and some other stuff).

In short we need a version of Rtools based at least on the gcc 4.8 series. The first step is to prove that this version successfully builds R from source.

Something that could help is to start releasing packages using C++11 to CRAN.

Comment: Any chance we will get Rcpp11 documentation in the near future? That would be a big incentive to writing packages.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler shipped with Rtools (gcc 4.6.3) is good enough to run the test suite of the devel version of Rcpp11, which uses features of C++11 quite extensively.

Details on unsupported features are available [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html), but the supported subset already feels like C++11. There were only a few things I had to compromise (delegated constructors and template aliases). They make code better, but we can live without them for now.